# Are `return nil` and `return` interchangeable?

Tags: swift

I don't completely understand, can I use `return` and `return nil` interchangeably? Are `return` and `return nil` similar return type?

Here are two instances of a code.

1st instance:

```
func naming(name: Int) -> String? {
    switch name {
        case 0: return "Neo"
        case 1: return "Matrix"
        default: return nil
    }
}
naming(name: 2)   // nil
```

2nd instance:

```
guard let video = try? avplayer else {
    print("Unable to load a movie")
    return
}
```

Comment: No, its very different if a function returns nothing (Void) or if it returns a value that can be nil. In your example you would get a compilation error if you wrote `default: return` or if you wrote `return nil` in that guard statement

Comment: Return nil is returning null to the optional value of whatever is requested while a basic return is exiting the function basically.

Comment: If you replace `return nil` by  `return` in your first example then you'll notice that it does *not* compile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope they're not the same.

Returning `nil` is used when you need to return a value but that value can be optional. So in your example:

```
func naming(name: Int) -> String? {
    switch name {
        case 0: return "Neo"
        case 1: return "Matrix"
        default: return nil
    }
}
```

The function is expecting a `String` OR a `nil` value to be returned, hence `String?`. The question mark on the end indicates that the `String` is optional. When you call `naming(name: 2)` that calls the `switch` statement and doesn't find a value corresponding to the number 2, so defaults to returning `nil`.

Putting `return` like in your second example just stops the rest of the function from executing. So:

```
function loadVideo() {
    guard let video = try? avplayer else {
        print("Unable to load a movie")
        return
    }
    print("hello")
}
```

If the `avplayer` variable is nil then the `guard` statement will execute its `else` statement and print out `Unable to load a movie` then `return` from the function. This will prevent `hello` from being printed.

Answer (score 3):

No both are not the same!

`return` without any argument returns `Void`. This form of the `return` statement can only be used with a function that returns `Void`.

Once the `return` statement executes, the function exits and no more code in your function executes.

Answer (score 2):

simple answer to your question is NO

in your example

```
func naming(name: Int) -> String? /* reference */ {
    switch name {
        case 0: return "Neo"
        case 1: return "Matrix"
        default: return nil
    }
}
```

/* reference */
you are expected to return optional String here this could be string value or nil
if you decided to return only without value you will get compilation error

- in the second example I would like you to imagine that this is a void function to understand it more clearly

```
func naming(name: Int) {
    switch name {
        case 0: return "Neo" /* reference */
        case 1: return "Matrix" /* reference */
        default: return nil /* reference */
    }
}
```

you should be getting compilation error on /* reference */ if you tried to return any value from this function and you could return at any time without any value depending on your business

- so consider the guard let is a void function for safety swift does check the value for you if it has a value it will make the value /* video */ available in the next lines else it will return from the function and will not execute the rest of the function code